# How to set Image on run time in android

Tags: android, listview

I want to ask that if i want to add images on runtime how can i do it??...I mean I have a list of Countries in which there name and flag is given.I create the List (and set in adapter )but I do not get how to add image relative to its country

```
enter code here
package com.example.hp.myapplication;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lvProduct;
    private ProductListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Country> mProductList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        lvProduct = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_product);

        mProductList = new ArrayList<>();

        Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName ()  + R.drawable.afghanistan);
        String Path = path.toString();

        Uri path1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName ()  + R.drawable.portugal);
        String Path1 = path1.toString();

        //Add sample data for list
        //We can get data from DB, webservice here
        mProductList.add(new Country(1, "iPhone4", 200, "Apple iPhone4 16GB",Path));
        mProductList.add(new Country(3, "iPhone4S", 250, "Apple iPhone4S 16GB",Path1));
        mProductList.add(new Country(4, "iPhone5", 300, "Apple iPhone5 16GB",Path));
        mProductList.add(new Country(5, "iPhone5S", 350, "Apple iPhone5S 16GB",Path1));
        mProductList.add(new Country(6, "iPhone6", 400, "Apple iPhone6 16GB",Path));
        mProductList.add(new Country(7, "iPhone6S", 450, "Apple iPhone6S 16GB",Path1));
        mProductList.add(new Country(8, "iPhone7", 500, "Apple iPhone7 16GB",Path));
        mProductList.add(new Country(9, "iPhone7S", 600, "Apple iPhon7S 16GB",Path1));
        mProductList.add(new Country(10, "iPhone8", 700, "Apple iPhone8 16GB",Path));
        mProductList.add(new Country(11, "iPhone8S", 800, "Apple iPhone8S 16GB",Path1));

        //Init adapter
        adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mProductList);
        lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);

        lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Do something
                //Ex: display msg with product id get from view.getTag
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked product id =" + view.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
enter code here
package com.example.hp.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by HP on 16-Feb-17.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Country> mProductList;

    //Constructor

    public ProductListAdapter(Context mContext, List<Country> mProductList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
//        mProductList=new ArrayList<Country>();
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.mProductList = mProductList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mProductList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mProductList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ViewHolder holder;
        Country p = mProductList.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            holder.price= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
            holder.Description= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
            holder.img= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IMAGE);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        int number=p.getPrice();
        String numberAsString = Integer.toString(number);


        holder.name.setText(p.getName());
        holder.price.setText(numberAsString);
        holder.Description.setText(p.getDescription());
        holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.spain);
        return convertView;

    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView name;
        TextView price;
        TextView Description;
        ImageView img;
    }

}
enter code here
package com.example.hp.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by HP on 16-Feb-17.
 */
public class Country {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private String description;
    private String ImageUri;


    //Constructor

    public Country(int id, String name, int price, String description,String uri)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.ImageUri=uri;
    }

    //Setter, getter

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImage()
    {
        return ImageUri;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are always setting R.drawable.spain as drawable. That might be the problem...?

Comment: Yup i know that but how to change it to desirable output?

Answer (score 1):

The simples solution might be to add the Resource id to your Country class:

```
mProductList.add(new Country(11, "iPhone8S", 800, "Apple iPhone8S 16GB",R.drawable.portugal));
```

---

```
public Country(int id, String name, int price, String description,id resId){
    ...
    this.resId=resId;
}

public String getResId(){
    return resId;
}
```

---

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    ViewHolder holder;
    Country p = mProductList.get(position);
    ....
    holder.img.setImageResource(p.getResId);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: what is "id resId"?in the paramters

Comment: the Resource id. For example R.drawable.portugal. Just pass this id to your country class and use it in the getview

Answer (score 0):

As explained by FierceFox, you set the following image for every item:

`holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.spain);`

What you want instead is setting the image of the country.

`holder.img.setImageResource(country.getDrawableId());`

You need to completely remove the URI here:

```
mProductList.add(new Country(1, "iPhone4", 200, "Apple iPhone4 16GB",Path));
```

and replace it with the drawable id:

```
mProductList.add(new Country(1, "iPhone4", 200, "Apple iPhone4 16GB", R.drawable.portugal));
```

I don't know what you were trying to do with this URI, as you can see `setImageResource` takes `@DrawableRes int`, meaning you are supposed to just give it the drawable resource id, no need to store any URI.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am telling steps with basics.

- First of all you need to put all png/ jpg files into the drawable
  folder which is located under res folder in your main project
  hierarchy.
- Now in your Country object, just add one more parameter for resource ID, like this.

  MyCountryClass {

  ```
  int countryCode; 
  String countryName;
  int countryResId;

  }
  ```

Now at the adapter, do like this way.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_country_list_item, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListData countryListData = getItem(position);

        mViewHolder.tvCountryName.setText(countryListData.getCountryName());
        mViewHolder.IVDesc.setImageResource(R.id.my_country_name);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Now at activity class just prepare your list and set the adapter with list.